# Are there anyone master in Python?

Tags: printing, return

I know there are differences between print and return function, but sometimes, it does the same effect when you get the outputs. Under this condition, how do we differentiate between print and return?

Comment: `return` is not a function, but a statement: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement

Comment: did u try to google it? :S https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/518ffbfeb3f05c44fe001395

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem there, in fact you are confusing them, but also there are some changes between Python 2 and Python 3.

As Micha said, `return` is an statement, that would only work if it is inside a function, and would return a parameter list if it is present: [return statement doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=return#grammar-token-return_stmt)

And now we have `print` that depending on the version of Python you are using (Python 3 is the recommended version to use now), you will have either an statement or a function.  As of Python 2, `print` is an statement that evaluates and prints the list of expressions directly to standard input: [print doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=return#grammar-token-print_stmt)

But in Python 3, `print` is a more complex function, which its default behaviour is to print directly to standard output i.e. screen; but you can modify it with its other arguments: [print function doc Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Print statement is not longer available in Python 3.